# Chinese Remainder Theorem to Prove There Exist m consecutive non-prime-powers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm trying to prove that there exists any m > 0 consecutive non-prime-powers. Where a prime power is $2^2$ or $5^3$. One set of consecutive nonprime powers is 33,34,35,36

I know that the def of CRT requires that the moduli be coprime. I also know that if a number is not a prime power, its divisible by at least 2 distinct primes. So based on that I set up (all ps are distinct)

$$n+0≡0(mod (p_0p_1))$$
$$n+1≡0(mod(p_2p_3))$$
$$n+2≡0(mod(p_4p_5))$$
$$...n+(m-1)≡0(mod(p_{2m-2}p_{2m-1}))$$
$$...n≡-m-1(mod(p_{2m-2}p_{2m-1}))$$

Is it enough to just say that CRT guarantees a solution at this point?

That feels too simple

Also, for guidance, I saw a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1283246/780519)

But was a little worried because mine looks a bit different.

Comment: Can you provide an example of consecutive integers which are powers of non-primes? Apart from {0,1} of course!

Comment: @cosmo Reassociate: non (prime-powers), not (non-prime) powers.

Comment: Your proof looks fine and identical to the linked solution.  @cosmo I think the OP is asking about non prime-powers, not non-prime powers.

Comment: Actually, you should have a $-m+1$ not $-m-1$ on the last line. Other than that fine.

Comment: Quick question -- are we sure p0...pm are all unique? @tkf

Comment: @MelanieSanders You are free to choose any primes $p_0,\cdots, p_{2m-1}$ as long as they are all distinct.  As there are infinitely many distinct prime numbers, we know there exist distinct prime numbers $p_0,\cdots, p_{2m-1}$.  Choosing different primes will give you a different solution for $n$.  Whatever primes you pick, you will get $m$ consecutive numbers $n, n+1,\cdots, n+m-1$   which are not prime powers.